M365 powershell script that can assign license to a user account and assign a group after a certain period has passed
I am automating onboarding process for employees and would like a powershell script that can talk with M365 admin center to find the user account and assign license and also modify exchange custom attributes to a certain value, Will also need it at a later time assign a certain group to that user

SO is not a free code writing service. Even if it was, your question scope is far too broad; it has several different tasks that you should break down and work on separately and then combine. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to do that and to solve the problem yourself. When that happens, come back and ask a more specific question, include your efforts to solve the problem, and we can try to help.
